# ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string - JAVA / Oracle

Tags: java, oracle

I am converting my date input string in `MM-dd-YYYY` format to `SQL timestamp` format using the below query:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-YYYY", Locale.ENGLISH);
java.util.Date endDate = format.parse(myEndDateString);
endDateTimestamp = Calendar.getInstance();
endDateTimestamp.setTime(endDate);
endDateTimestamp.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

The timestamp has now been updated in the format as expected.

```
30-DEC-18 12.00.00.000000000 AM
```

I have a few rows in my DB updated like this. Now, when I wish to obtain the dates in future to this using:

```
select * from my_records where end_dt > sysdate;
```

I get an exception :

> ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input
>   string.

Is there any other way to update the string as timestamp or should the query be modified?

**UPDATE**:
My table column *end_dt* is in `TIMESTAMP` type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `END_DT` column's datatype was `DATE`, then your query would work. It appears that it is not, but `VARCHAR2`. If that's so, you'll have to apply `TO_DATE` function to it with appropriate format mask in order to make it work. For example:

```
select * From my_records
where to_date(substr(end_dt, 1, 9), 'dd-mon-yy') > sysdate
```

---

```
30-DEC-18 12.00.00.000000000 AM
---------
this makes SUBSTR(end_dt, 1, 9), and its format mask is dd-mon-yy
```

**[EDIT]**

You said that its datatype is timestamp. If it was, then your query would work. Have a look at this example:

```
SQL> create table test (end_dt timestamp);

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values (systimestamp);

1 row created.

SQL> select * From test where end_dt < sysdate;

END_DT
----------------------------------------------------
02.02.19 20:42:08,375000

SQL>
```

Can you verify that it really *is* TIMESTAMP (not that it looks like it, but really is). Do that by running DESC command:

```
SQL> desc test
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ---------------
 END_DT                                             TIMESTAMP(6)

SQL>
```

Comment: Yes @Littlefoot. Generally, when I update the timestamp via a query, it works. But when I do the same, (i.e) update the timestamp via my java class, it throws the exception specified. That is what I am concerned of.

Comment: Huh, via Java class ... I know less than zero about Java so - if that's where the problem is, I hope that someone else will be able to assist. Sorry, but I'm afraid I can't help any further.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying from Oracle end @Littlefoot. You have resolved my query from Oracle end.